# Git: почему невозможно вернуть состояние файла?

Tags: git, файлы, восстановление

Имеется следующий коммит, информация о котором получена через команду `git log -p "base/1352180832kivved34jz/text.html"`:

```
commit 8eeb29f220f40b8abbbe0002a2fceb7cb107cb48
Author: xintrea
Date:   Mon Dec 19 09:00:17 2016 +0300
    FirstStadyCommit
diff --git a/base/1352180832kivved34jz/text.html b/base/1352180832kivved34jz/text.html
index 5074ebb..5ba83ab 100644
Binary files a/base/1352180832kivved34jz/text.html and b/base/1352180832kivved34jz/text.html differ
```

Я пытаюсь восстановить состояние файла text.html таким, каким он был в этом коммите:

```
git checkout 8eeb29f220f40b8abbbe0002a2fceb7cb107cb48 "/base/1352180832kivved34jz/text.html"

fatal: Could not switch to '/base/1352180832kivved34jz/': No such file or directory
```

Почему возникает ошибка?

Comment: "/base" - это путь от корня, причем корня диска. А надо писать путь от текущей директории.

Comment: Блин, забыл об этом. Скопировал из строки a/base/1352180832kivved34jz/text.html без "a".

Comment: И вообще возьмите за привычку разделять файлы от опций самого клиента опцией --

Comment: В man pages гита о такой опции не говорится.